# How to Update a Unlocked package customField picklist value Using MetaData api

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, metadata, custom-metadata

I am to update my picklist value to capitalize it by deploying but i am getting this error

> Picklist value: In Production in picklist: Merchandise_Status__c not found

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Merchandise_Status__c</fullName>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Merchandise Status</label>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Picklist</type>
    <valueSet>
        <restricted>true</restricted>
        <valueSetDefinition>
            <sorted>false</sorted>
            <value>
                <fullName>Not Available</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
                <label>Not Available</label>
            </value>
            <value>
                <fullName>Goods Requested</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
                <label>Goods Requested</label>
            </value>
            <value>
                <fullName>Production Approved</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
                <label>Production Approved</label>
            </value>
            <value>
                <fullName>In production</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
                <label>In Production</label>
            </value>
            <value>
                <fullName>Available</fullName>
                <default>false</default>
                <label>Available</label>
            </value>
        </valueSetDefinition>
    </valueSet>
</CustomField>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify the sObject name this field is on in the "fullName"

```
<fullName>sObject.Merchandise_Status__c</fullName>
```

(It would be my suggestion to export the metadata first, then modify it and deploy it.  That way you are sure to get the correct format/layout.)